# Conj of multiple elements into a vector at the same time

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure

I would like to conjoin elements inside a vector into some vectors which are inside a parent vector.

```
example:
;; I have a vector [["1" "2" "3"] ["4" "5"]]
;; and another vector ["6" "7"]
```

I did this:

```
(map (fn [row]
       (conj row ["6" "7"]))
     [["1" "2" "3"] ["4" "5"]])
;;=> (["1" "2" "3" ["6" "7"]] ["4" "5" ["6" "7"]])
```

but I would like my result in this format:

```
 ;;=> (["1" "2" "3" "6" "7"] ["4" "5" "6" "7"])
```

Please kindly point me in the right directioin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want `conj` (appends the vector as element). You want `concat` or `into` instead:

```
(map (fn [row] (concat row ["6" "7"])) [["1" "2" "3"] ["4" "5"]])
=> (("1" "2" "3" "6" "7") ("4" "5" "6" "7"))
```

or more sucintly:

```
(map #(into % ["6" "7"]) [["1" "2" "3"] ["4" "5"]])
=> (["1" "2" "3" "6" "7"] ["4" "5" "6" "7"])
```

(`into` preserves the vectors, so it's probably the one you want. See the documentation for the differences between the two).

Answer (score 1):

Your original code is very close.  `conj` adds each element you pass.  So you basically just lacked an `apply`:

```
user=> (map (fn [row] (apply conj row ["6" "7"])) [["1" "2" "3"] ["4" "5"]])
(["1" "2" "3" "6" "7"] ["4" "5" "6" "7"])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is a bit simpler solution.  It uses
 the `glue` function from [the Tupelo Core library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo), along with a `for` statement:

```
(ns xyz
  (:require [tupelo.core :as tc]....

(def data [ [1 2 3] [4 5] ] )
(tc/spyx 
  (for [curr-vec data]
    (tc/glue curr-vec [6 7] )))

;=> (for [curr-vec data] (tc/glue curr-vec [6 7])) => ([1 2 3 6 7] [4 5 6 7])
```